# Convert multiple data within a row into a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dict that looks as follows:

```
print([time])
```

output

```
[{(0, 0): 0.0, (0, 1): 88.6, (0, 2): 60.4, (0, 3): 43.9, (0, 4): 40.5, (1, 0): 89.0, (1, 1): 0.0, (1, 2): 120.1, (1, 3): 59.2, (1, 4): 75.9, (2, 0): 84.9, (2, 1): 137.9, (2, 2): 0.0, (2, 3): 109.1, (2, 4): 97.4, (3, 0): 36.1, (3, 1): 48.7, (3, 2): 67.2, (3, 3): 0.0, (3, 4): 23.0, (4, 0): 84.2, (4, 1): 48.1, (4, 2): 115.3, (4, 3): 54.4, (4, 4): 0.0}]
```

I used the following commands to convert the dict into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Time' : time}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

output:

|  |  | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0.0 |
|  | 1 | 96.0 |
|  | 2 | 124.1 |
|  | 3 | 80.1 |
|  | 4 | 93.2 |
| 1 | 0 | 102.5 |
|  | 1 | 0.0 |
|  | 2 | 159.1 |
|  | 3 | 132.3 |
|  | 4 | 175.3 |
| 2 | 0 | 115.9 |
|  | 1 | 196.1 |
|  | 2 | 0.0 |
|  | 3 | 164.5 |
|  | 4 | 168.0 |
| 3 | 0 | 70.3 |
|  | 1 | 130.9 |
|  | 2 | 194.4 |
|  | 3 | 0.0 |
|  | 4 | 58.9 |
| 4 | 0 | 68.1 |
|  | 1 | 164.1 |
|  | 2 | 192.2 |
|  | 3 | 77.2 |
|  | 4 | 0.0 |

How can I change this to appear as follows:

| 0 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 96.0 | 124.1 | 80.1 | 93.2 |
| 1 | 102.5 | 0.0 | 159.1 | 132.3 | 175.5 |
| 2 | 115.9 | 196.1 | 0.0 | 164.5 | 168.0 |
| 3 | 70.3 | 130.9 | 194.4 | 0.0 | 58.9 |
| 4 | 68.1 | 164.1 | 192.2 | 77.2 | 0.0 |

in pandas

Comment: You forgot to paste the expected output

Comment: Im still editing sry

Comment: Please paste data as **text**, not an image.  Try and copy/paste the image into the terminal to help someone debug code.  Not fun ...

Comment: Finally got it to write, sorry about that

Comment: The "How can I change this to appear as follows:" section is the expected output

Comment: Could you post the code that will generate the dataframe instead of a table so that we can test solutions? Right now it is hard to use because `pd.read_clipboard()` will not work when there are blank spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `unstack`

```py
out = df.unstack(level=1)
```

```
print(out)

      0      1      2      3     4
0   0.0   88.6   60.4   43.9  40.5
1  89.0    0.0  120.1   59.2  75.9
2  84.9  137.9    0.0  109.1  97.4
3  36.1   48.7   67.2    0.0  23.0
4  84.2   48.1  115.3   54.4   0.0
```

Comment: Fyi if you're unstacking the inner most level of a multiindex, then you can use unstack() no argument, default level is -1.

Comment: @ScottBoston Thank your for pointing this out!